# implode numeric nested array of associative array

Tags: php, arrays

This might be duplicate of several questions.
I am having an dynamic array

```
Array
(
    [gender] => Male
    [age] => Array
        (
            [0] => 18-25 years
            [1] => 26-32 years
        )

    [name] => Nagesh
    [emailid] => nagesh@ccomsys.net
)
```

I want to store this array in HTML table as key in one column and value in another 
Example.

```
__________________________________
Gender | Male
_______|__________________________
Age    | 18-25 years, 26-32 years
_______|__________________________
Name   | Nagesh
_______|__________________________
Email  | nagesh@ccomsys.net
_______|__________________________
```

I am getting key and value for associative array but how can I implode age array.

I tried below code

```
$post = $this->request->post;
$age_array = array_column($post, 'age');
$age = '';

    foreach($post as $key => $value) {
        if($key == "age"){
            $age = implode(",", $age_array);
        }
        echo $age. "<br>";
        echo $key. "<br>";
        if($key != "age"){
            echo $value. "<br>";
        } else {
            echo $age;
        }
    }
```

Thanks advance.

Comment: `$age = implode(",", $value);` ?

Comment: I don't see anyone (including the OP) using table elements in their code, despite the OP asking for a HTML table output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a few minor adjustments:

- I added `ucfirst()` to the first column to match your desired output.
- I used an inline conditional to check if array values were arrays, to appropriately imploded array before echoing.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2bed4550af8f0050edb3c8921856aef6ed263714))

```
$post=[
    'gender'=>'Male',
    'age'=>['18-25 years','26-32 years'],
    'name'=>'Nagesh',
    'emailid'=>'nagesh@ccomsys.net'
];

echo '<table border=1>';
    foreach($post as $k=>$v){
        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>',ucfirst($k),'</td><td>',(is_array($v)?implode(', ',$v):$v),'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
echo '</table>';
```

Unrendered Output:

```
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td>Gender</td><td>Male</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Age</td><td>18-25 years, 26-32 years</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td><td>Nagesh</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Emailid</td><td>nagesh@ccomsys.net</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Rendered output available via runnable snippet:

```html
<table border=1><tr><td>Gender</td><td>Male</td></tr><tr><td>Age</td><td>18-25 years, 26-32 years</td></tr><tr><td>Name</td><td>Nagesh</td></tr><tr><td>Emailid</td><td>nagesh@ccomsys.net</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: can you tell how can I insert whole table as code in db. I tried as 
`$table = "<table border='1'>";
  foreach($post as $key => $value) {
   $table .= "<tr><td>".ucfirst($key) . "</td>";
   $table .= "<td>".(is_array($value) ? implode(",", $value) : $value)."</td></tr>";
  }
  $table .= "</table>";
  $description = addslashes($table);` 
`$sql = "INSERT INTO `" . DB_PREFIX . "event_form` SET `customer_id` = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "', `event_id` = '" . $event_id . "',  `description` = '" . $description . "'";`

Comment: But I am getting output as
INSERT INTO `sm_event_form` SET `customer_id` = '152', `event_id` = '8', `description` = '
and table

Comment: I sorted out with this `htmlentities(addslashes($table))`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is working like what you expecting:

```
foreach($post as $key => $value) {
        echo $key. "<br>";
        if($key == "age"){
                $age = implode(",", $post[$key]);
                echo $age. "<br>";                
        }
        if($key != "age"){
            echo $value. "<br>";
        } else {
            //echo $age;
        }
    }
```

If you get multiple arrays means it will work. I changed small things in your condition:

```
foreach($post as $key => $value) {
        echo $key. "<br>";
        if(is_array($post[$key])){
                $age = implode(",", $post[$key]);
                echo $age. "<br>";

        }
        if(!is_array($post[$key])){
            echo $value. "<br>";
        } else {
            //echo $age;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you tell me if I dont know key name then how it can be done. Suppose instead of age array has hobbies. Now I know that is age because I have printed an array. But when I dont then how could I know that array has nested array.

Comment: You can check `if(is_array($post[$key])){` instead of `if($key == "age"){` you only give the age condition only. @NageshKatke

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following code:

```
if($key == "age"){
  $age = implode(",", $age_array);
}
```

with

```
if($key == "age"){
  $age = implode(",", $value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of data and you want to display it on a table. Instead of using implode(), why not just concatenate the two strings together?

```
Array
(
    [gender] => Male
    [age] => Array
        (
            [0] => 18-25 years
            [1] => 26-32 years
        )

    [name] => Nagesh
    [emailid] => nagesh@ccomsys.net
)
```

**PHP code:**

```
$post = $this->request->post;

foreach($post as $key => $value) {
  if($key == "age"){
    $age = $value[0].','.$value[1];
  }
  echo $age. "<br>";
  echo $key. "<br>";
  if($key != "age"){
    echo $value. "<br>";
  } else {
    echo $age;
  }
}
```

Comment: I cant use this as age values can be vary because whole array is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to code as follows...

```
foreach($post as $value){
    $gender = $value['gender'];
    $age = implode(',',$value['age']);
    $name = $value['name'];
    $email = $value['email'];
}
```

Comment: As I said array is dynamic so keys of associative array can be different. Not necessary array should be same everytime.

Comment: array keys different or order...?

Answer (score 0):

Change Your foreach loop with this one.

```
foreach($test as $key => $value) {
    $age = '';
    if($key == "age"){
        $age = implode(",", $value);
    }
    echo $age. "<br>";
    echo $key. "<br>";

    if($key != "age"){
        echo $value. "<br>";
    } else {
        echo $age;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$output = [];
//$array - your input data
foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
    $output[$key] =  (is_array($item)) ?  implode(', ', $item) : $item;
}
//print output
```